# SMTP Mail Issue - In Laravel Horizon Package

Tags: laravel, smtp

Horizon Version: 4.3.5
Laravel Version: 7.0
PHP Version: 7.3
Redis Driver & Version: predis/phpredis 1.1

Description:
Hi,

I am using Laravel Horizon package for sent mails to many users. (SMTP gmail)

I sent around 300 mails.

In Config/horizon.php

```
'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'processes' => 10,
            'tries' => 1,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

Initially mail sent successfully after some time processing most of mail not sent.

But in normal queue method all mails sent successfully, (Only time takes long).

Any one faced like that of issue. or do you know what mistake i did.
Guide to me

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That because Gmail SMTP limitations, you can't use Gmail SMTP for more than 500 messages per day (free account) of course with a daily sending limit see [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en#zippy=%2Cfree-trial-account-limits).